# Implementing Zend Framework 2 Autoloader

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-autoloader

Is it possible to replace ZF1 Autoloader with ZF2 Autoloader, as it seems that it could significantly increase performance ?

I didn't find any tutorials out there neither much material on this - I've just heard ZF2's Autoloader would be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ZF1 codebase uses `require_once` to include dependencies, ZF1 autoloader relies on include path which leads to poor performance results.

Migrating to ZF2 autoloader (or [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/)'s one) will not have a significant performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

You could update to Zend Framework v1.12, which backports some of the new autoloader functions from Zend Framework v2, see http://devzone.zend.com/2554/zend-framework-1-12-0-stable-released/